# ElasticsearchClient 7.16 mapping source from JSON file

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm migrating our app to new [ElastisearchClient](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java) for Java. We have few mapping/setting/properties configurations created in JSON files like here [Elastic mapping source 7.15](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-put-mapping.html#_mapping_source). Is it still possible to map sources as in these examples? Or is it fully migrated to:

> builders and functional patterns

Currently, we do it like this (RestHighLevelClient 7.14 Elastic):

```java
    String mapping = "mappings/file.json";
    String source = StringUtils.toString(new ClassPathResource(mapping).getInputStream(); //Converting to acceptable json 
    CreateIndex createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(name);
    createIndexRequest.source(source, XContentType.JSON);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible from 7.17.0 version – [Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/7.17/loading-json.html#_loading_an_index_definition_from_a_resource_file)

```java
    CreateIndexRequest req = CreateIndexRequest.of(b -> b
    .index("some-index")
    .withJson(input) //Insert here loaded json mapping
);
```